# Cannot delete item from dynamodb table

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have this function that adds an item to a dynamodb table. Upon success it is supposed to remove that same item from another table. I have this a api gateway trigger attached to this. When I test in postman. I get the following error. "The provided key element does not match the schema".

The partition keys are

First Table: 
Partition Key: CandidatEmail
Sort Key: Type

Second Table:
Partition Key: Date
Sort Key: Type

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set credentials
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./credentials.json');
// // set dynamodb object
var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-1',});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    function getTableName(counselor) {
        if(counselor == "Avery Rosser") {
            return "Licensed_Level"
        }
        else if (counselor == "Keshara Rosser") {
            return "Masters_Level"
        }
    }

  const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
        statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
        body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
             "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : false
        }

    });

    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);

    var params = {
      TableName: "Appointment",
      Item: {}
    }

    var deleteParams = {
      TableName: getTableName(body.counselor), 
       Key: { 
           "Date": {S: body.date}
        }
    };

    var appointment = {
        "CandidateEmail": {S: body.candidateEmail},
        "Date": {S: body.date},
        "Name": {S: body.name},
        "Duration": {S: body.duration},
        "Price": {S: body.price},
        "Location": {S: body.location},
        "Counselor": {S: body.counselor},
        "CandidateFirstName": {S: body.candidateFirstName},
        "CandidateLastName": {S: body.candidateLastName},
        "Type": {S: body.type},
    }

    params.Item = appointment;

    dynamo.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("error in put item", err)
        }
        else {
            dynamo.deleteItem(deleteParams, done)
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key. maybe you can use ConditionExpression attribute to deleteItem.

Comment: I added ConditionExpression: "#date = :date",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#date": "Date"
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":date": {S: body.date}
      } but still getting same error

Comment: let's wait for others even I'm not sure. till then you can run one more query to search that data and once you get the data you'll get both partition key and sort key. you can use scan function but it's little slow compare to query function. I've added one tag in your question so that right people reach this question.